# Why does a custom action filter need to inherit from both ActionFilterAttribute and IActionFilter?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I m first time creating a custom action filter and following this link http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters

They are saying to Extend `ActionFilterAttribute` class and also implement `IActionFilter` interface. `ActionFilterAttribute` already implement `IActionFilter`. I  m wondering why I need to implement Interface again in my attribute class. Is is something a must to do ? Will highly appreciate if you please can clear this ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify the interface again since the base class already implements it, it is redundant to add it again but it shouldn't harm anything either.

I also don't know why they are explicitly implementing the interface instead of overriding the existing virtual methods which already implement the interface.

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe it`s simply a mistake. for instance you can eather inherit from

> 1. FilterAttribute, IActionFilter

Or

> 2. ActionFilterAttribute

the first one provides low level behavior of MVC Attributes plus `Order` and `AllowMultiple` properties.
and the second one provides less details plus `OnResultExecuting`and `OnResultExecuted` capabilities.